# If I'm connected to device A don't connect to device B

Tags: bluetooth, tasker, automation, bluetooth-audio

I often find myself in my car following my wife until our commutes separate.
When arriving at stop signs for instance, my audio regularly cuts out and transfers to the BT Audio in her vehicle.

I'd like to create a solution, in Tasker, which is when I'm connected to the BT in my vehicle, don't connect to the BT in hers.

I've created the profile and am struggling with the task to accomplish disconnect BT from her device, or just prevent further BT connections.  Can anyone help?

The profile is set up as:
State > Net > BT Connected
The address of my vehicle.

So now I need a task to disconnect from the BT in the other car.  But I can't figure it out.

Comment: I was taking about Tasker. I've updated the question and added the tag. If you have an alternate way to accomplish the goal without Tasker, i would love to hear about it.

Comment: I haven't tried this but with [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) create a macro where trigger is Bluetooth connected to your device and action is disconnect Bluetooth audio (hers).  Your device needs to be paired and connected to test this. I don't use Tasker so can't help with that

Comment: @beeshyams with Tasker it would be the same. Haven't tried it, and todbanner didn't specify the profile set up – but basically it should be "condition: my car connected; task: disconnect hers".

Comment: @Izzy Agreed! perhaps you can give todbanner a sample task to achieve this, be sure to post as answer :)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat As I cannot verify it, I'd prefer todbanner to confirm that first. The question doesn't state how exactly the profile was set up, so it's hard to tell. From raw guessing, I'd say first try the "disconnect" beeshyams also recommended. If that doesn't work out, try "prevent" (didn't know there was such a thing).

Comment: Question updates with more info on profile setup.